How to set global variables when executing script on the command line?
I'd like to send session variables to a script that I'm executing on the command line.
The script first interprets whether or not I have access to perform certain actions and if not, it exits. So, this is the line of the code I'm inquiring about:
if ($_SESSION['permission']['chat'] !== '2') exit;

Normally, this is run as part of a web application but in my case, I want to run it from the command line. Is there a way to set $_SESSION['permission']['chat'] from the command line so that this IF statement would pass?

Session doesn't exist as a concept in the command-line. There's no such thing. The whole point of the Session is to manage the multiple potential connections from different places the server can receive into a web application, and thus be able to maintain state for different users. That's not something which is an issue for a command-line script, because only one user can interact with that instance of the script while it's running. Therefore it simply isn't available in the command-line environment.

I imagine you simply need instead to refer to the original source of information which was used to populate that Session variable in the web version - presumably there's a database table or file which defines some security roles or something. If you're wanting to use this script in both web and command-line contexts, a bit of refactoring is going to be needed, so you can re-use the same core functionality, but have different wrappers around it for each runtime environment.

If you need to persist data between multiple runs of a CLI script, use a file or database.

In a command-line context, PHP sessions don't exist as they do in a web environment. Sessions are designed to manage multiple user sessions through HTTP requests, maintaining a unique state for each user.
